# HTML5 Geolocation Permission Problem

Tags: html, permissions, geolocation

I am using Google Chrome extension of geolocation. It seems like even if I deny the permission, it still gives the location. I have even tried changing the location preferences by going to tools and setting them to *Not allow to detect the location*; but even then it still works.

How can this be answered ?

Comment: This question needs clarification. What is that "extension" you speak of? (Please provide a link) Also, are having a problem as a programmer(i.e. geolocation does not work) or user (geolocation *does* work although you denied it)? If it's the latter, please ask this question at http://superuser.com . Also, bear in mind that geolocation does not need cooperation of the browser; geolocation purely by IP can be accurate to about 20km.

Comment: The specification for Geolocation strictly defines that permission for obtaining a user's position must be sought by the browser.

Comment: @Ian Devlin : I had used the notifications API for the permission for geolocation. When I deny the permission; it still shows me the coordinates.I had even denied the location permission from Chrome preferences/tools. But it still WORKS !..How ?

Answer (score 1):

The following piece of code should give you a position on e where the `alert('Position');` is and in your case when you deny permission should pop up the alert with `alert('This should pop up');`

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (
    function (e) {
        alert('Position');
    }, function (e) {
        alert('This should pop up');
    }
);
```